# Topology filters and convergence

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective, continous and open mapping, $x\in X$ and $\mathcal F$ a filter on $Y$ such that converges to $f(x)$. Prove that exist a filter $\mathcal C$ on $X$ such that $f(\mathcal C)=\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal C$ converges to x.

Well we have to prove an existence so I really have no idea of wich set magically will satisfy what I need. Some help would be great.

Maybe the inverse image of $\mathcal F$ which is a filter basis on X because the inverse image of each member of $\mathcal F$ is non empty, I am not quite sure.

Comment: Ok, you've made a guess as to what filter to use (the filter generated by the preimage of each set in $\mathcal{F}$). Did you try to check that this choice works? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: How to prove indeed $\mathcal C$ indeed converges to x

Comment: How is $f(\mathcal{C})$ defined for a filter $\mathcal{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Since $f$ is surjective, the preimage of a nonempty set is nonempty. 
By the conditions, $\mathcal C$ has to contain all neighborhoods of $x$ and all sets $f^{-1}(B)$ for $B\in\mathcal F$.
Show that they indeed generate a filter, which fulfills the requirements.

Comment: Beyond showing that those sets generate a filter, you'll need to show that this filter's image is only $\mathcal F$ and not some larger filter. I'd expect this to need your  assumption that $f$ is an open mapping.